# Why Use Argo CD in Combination with Tekton

Tags: openshift, argocd, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am configuring a cloud-native OpenShift CI/CD process using Tekton. Tekton has the option to [trigger via events](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/master/docs/README.md) and also has the option to [deploy directly to a cluster](https://github.com/IBM/tekton-tutorial/blob/master/tekton/tasks/deploy-using-kubectl.yaml). Given this functionality, I am confused of the ideal use case for Argo CD.

Argo CD appears to share very similar functionality with Tekton except lacks the ability to run builds. If I can build *and* deploy apps entirely via Tekton, what advantage does Argo provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of preference.

Yes, Tekton is good for a Build Pipeline and can also be used for deployment.

There are many different ways to deploy to Kubernetes

- With `kubectl apply -f` using [declarative manifests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)
- With `kubectl apply -k` using [kustomization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) (e.g. to easier maitain multiple environments)
- With ArgoCD, using GitOps to sync a git repository to the cluster, see [example in a Tekton Pipeline](https://github.com/sdaschner/tekton-argocd-example/blob/main/pipeline/task-deploy.yaml#L67-L74)
- With [kpt](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kpt) that is similar to kustomize but can manage "bundles" from git
- With [helm](https://helm.sh/), using templates and [charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/)
- With [flagger](https://www.weave.works/oss/flagger/) to use e.g. Canary Deployments

They can all deploy to Kubernetes. Which method you use depends on your preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent clarification. Is it correct to state the primary advantage of integrating Argo CD is to take advantage of GitOps? It appears Tekton by itself lends more to traditional imperative CI/CD whereas Argo CD integration is what allows declarative GitOps workflows.

Comment: yes, more or less. However, Tekton and traditional CI/CD is also declarative when using Kubernetes manifests and `kubectl apply` or `kustomize`.